# How to deploy Vue (Front-End) & Spring Boot (Back-End) app on Azure (pref via Azure Pipelines)?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure and cannot find any resource on the Internet on this, although I would think this is a common task.

I have a Vue.js frontend and Spring Boot backend. Auth using JWT. Front and back are two separate projects in separate repositories.

Now, I want the whole deployed on Azure, preferably via some Azure release pipelines triggered by Azure repos.

In what Azure products should I deploy these two projects? Should they be both in a separate VM? Also, how do I configure the frontend to use the correct base url of the backend so that it can fetch data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your frontend should be deployed to Azure Storage:

https://medium.com/@matthewleak/deploying-a-static-website-to-azure-storage-using-azure-devops-fa0bed457d07

Your spring boot can be deployed on App Service:

https://medium.com/microsoftazure/the-power-of-azure-devops-projects-for-java-apps-cda6c69bef0e

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would you advice on the last part in my question: "Also, how do I configure the frontend to use the correct base url of the backend so that it can fetch data?".

Comment: the baseUrl will be the url of your backend. https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net Or if you have a domain, then it will be your domain name https://example.com